# How to dynamically create custom xml element (or custom javafx scene control) in java

Tags: java, xml

I am new to java, so please take it easy on me. I am trying to dynamically populate a xml file named clients.xml with clients. Each client needs to be displayed individually inside a VBox.

The xml for creating a individual client is as follows:

```
            <HBox fx:id="clientBox" alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="52.0" prefWidth="194.0">
                       <children>
                          <ImageView fitHeight="35.0" fitWidth="35.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                             <image>
                                <Image url="@../assets/images/user-icon.png" />
                             </image>
                          </ImageView>
                          <VBox>
                             <children>
                                <HBox>
                                   <children>
                                      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name:">
                                         <HBox.margin>
                                            <Insets right="10.0" />
                                         </HBox.margin>
                                      </Text>
                                      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" styleClass="fn-14" text="Liam Smith" />
                                   </children>
                                </HBox>
                                <HBox prefHeight="10.0" />
                                <HBox>
                                   <children>
                                      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ID:">
                                         <HBox.margin>
                                            <Insets right="10.0" />
                                         </HBox.margin>
                                      </Text>
                                      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" styleClass="fn-14" text="968745632952" />
                                   </children>
                                </HBox>
                             </children>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets left="5.0" right="5.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </VBox>
                          <VBox alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <children>
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete">
                                   <styleClass>
                                      <String fx:value="background-transparent" />
                                      <String fx:value="fn-14" />
                                      <String fx:value="fill-red" />
                                   </styleClass>
                                   <VBox.margin>
                                      <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                                   </VBox.margin>
                                </Button>
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                                   <styleClass>
                                      <String fx:value="background-transparent" />
                                      <String fx:value="fn-14" />
                                      <String fx:value="fill-green" />
                                   </styleClass>
                                   <VBox.margin>
                                      <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                                   </VBox.margin>
                                </Button>
                             </children>
                          </VBox>
                       </children>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </padding>
                       <styleClass>
                          <String fx:value="background-light-grey" />
                          <String fx:value="hover-hand" />
                          <String fx:value="hover-light-blue" />
                       </styleClass>
                       <VBox.margin>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </VBox.margin>
                    </HBox>
```

What I would like to do is dynamically create the above clientBox inside a HBox with the fx:id of clientSection via a loop in my clients controller.

Basically what I am trying to do is in ClientsCotroller, do something like:

```
   for (Client client : Bank.getInstance().getClients()) {
        clientSection.getChildren().add(new clientBox() );
    }
```

Please could I be advised as to how I could possibly achieve this.
Kind regards, Matt.

Comment: You might get better help if you state which XML library you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So all I ended up doing was creating a custom control. I separated the xml I wanted to create dynamically into its own fxml file named listItem.fxml.

listItem.fxml

```
  <fx:root alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="78.0" prefWidth="363.0" stylesheets="@../css/styles.css" type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

  <!-- xml for listitem comes here -->

</fx:root>
```

I then created a separate controller for this file named ListItemControl.java.

ListItem.java

```
public class ListItemControl extends HBox {
       // associate the control to the fxml
  public ListItemControl() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
          FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/company/fxml/listItem.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    }
```

after that every time I wanted to use the custom component, I would create a new one like this:

```
ListItemControl clientBoxControl = new ListItemControl();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB as xml to Java objects convertor. Following to these examples : https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-for-xml-with-java try to marshal/unmarshal the elements.